# Will My order number generator work correctly?

Tags: c#, database, unique-constraint, business-logic

I need order number,that is not order ID but is unique. I generate from time,member id,random.
...

```
bll.DataAccess.BeginTransaction();            
    try
    {
        T_ProductOrd order = new T_ProductOrd();
        DateTime tm = DateTime.Now;
        order.F_MemberID = user.F_MemberID;
        order.F_Status = (short)OrderStatus.waitpay;
        order.F_Price = items.Sum(i => i.num * i.price);
        do {                 
            order.F_OrderNum = tm.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + (user.F_MemberID % 1000).ToString("0000") + new Random((int)tm.Ticks).Next(0, 9999).ToString("0000");
            bll.Save(order);
        } while (bll.FindCount(p => p.F_OrderNum == order.F_OrderNum) > 1);
```

My question is :do...while query and regenerate in database transaction will work fine?or still possible throw unique conflict when commit?
If is not work fine 100%.how can I fixed?

Comment: Why not just use `Guid`?

Comment: It's rather unlikely that at the same time persons with the same member ID will register, right?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the `do while`? It currently looks like you're _saving duplicates_ until you finally save a unique one.

Comment: Guid is not Human-readable.and member ID I only use low four bit orelse is too long

Comment: Refer [this SO on GUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371762/what-exactly-is-guid-why-and-where-i-should-use-it)

Comment: If you already have a database, why not simply use it's built in auto-increment mechanism instead of creating your own?

Comment: @Zohar Peled I need other order number for user query.database auto id is not good idea for remember.